# Why this code show this "control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] " ERROR?

Tags: c

I tried to program to add the previous three numbers of an nth number recursively until attaining
the nth value

for example ;

func(n) = {return a if  n = 1 ; return b if n= 2 ;return c if n = 3 ;return func(n - 1) + func( n - 2) + func( n - 3) if n  > 3}
}

```
int find_nth_term(int n , int a ,int b,int c)
{
 if (n == 2)
 {
  return b;
  
 }
 else if (n == 1)
 {
  return a;
 }
 else if (n == 3)
 {
   return c;
 }
 else if (n > 3)
 {
   int temp = a + b +c;
   a= b;
   b = c;
   c = temp;
   return find_nth_term(n-1, a ,b,c);
 }
}


 int main() {
    int n, a, b, c;
  
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &a, &b, &c);
    int ans = find_nth_term(n, a, b, c);
 
    printf("%d", ans); 
    return 0;
```

Comment: What should happen when `n < 1`? If you want to leave that case explicitly undefined, you'll need to communicate that to your compiler/linter. For GCC/Clang, that's done with [__builtin_unreachable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)

Comment: Also note that control reaching the end of a non-void function only emits a warning, not an error. But, that warning is being promoted to an error since you explicitly asked the compiler to stop compiling if that warning is emitted (via the flag `-Werror=return-type` or possibly just `-Werror`)

Answer (score 1):

### The function must return an int

Look at your code and focus on `if`, `else-if` blocks. Those blocks matches if `n` is 1,2,3 or greater and `return` something. But, what if `n` is 0 or less than 0? What does it return? Which if block caches it? This is why the compiler is complaining. In all cases the function must return something.

So, you'll have to add an `else` block after the last `else-if` or you can add a `return` expression at the bottom of function block. Like `return -1`;

```
 else if (n > 3)
 {
   int temp = a + b +c;
   a= b;
   b = c;
   c = temp;
   return find_nth_term(n-1, a ,b,c);
 } else {
   return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the conditions on `n` hold, e.g. when `n` is negative, the execution of the function will reach the final curly brace without having returned any value.

The most important observation here, is that there is no need to use `else` in combination with `return`. The function either returns or continues. An example with some random numbers:

```
int some_function(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 5;

    if (n > 3)
        return 11;

    if (n < 100)
        return 41;

    return -1;
}
```